# Is it possible to create several Edit Blocks that Add, Edit, and Delete Records within one Omniscript?

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity

I`m facing the issue trying to create the second Edit Block within one Omniscript.

Prerequisites:

1. The Name of an element in Omniscript can`t be used twice.
2. The Edit Label in the Edit Block Properties and the Name of the Remote action should be the same.

I try to name Remote action other than "Edit" (because I already used this name in my previous Edit Block), and rename Edit Label accordingly.

**Name of the Remote action**

[image: Name of the Remote action]

**Edit Label**

[image: Edit Label]

Then I receive such a result - two buttons are added to the UI.:

[image: buttons]

It looks like it`s only possible to name this fields with reserved "Edit", "New", "Delete".
But it means we cannot use the Edit Block twice, as we cannot repeat names of elements.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the 'Name' field with your edit block's name, then end in -new:

(Edit Block Element Name)-New

The Remote Method in the Remote Properties needs to be 'New' which can be reused.

Help Article on this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_creatingeditingand_deleting_records_with_default_actions_and_sobject_mapping.htm&type=5